# Error on Parameter C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need verify the Parameter `RGP, PEIXE, DATA_REGISTRO` for my method return true. But on PEIXE parameter this giving error:

> Expects 'PEIXE' parameter, which was not provided.

PEIXE is a Varchar type on SQL, RGP is a Int type and DATA_REGISTRO is a Date type.

```
 public bool Search_RGP_Cadastro(int param_RGP, string param_date, string param_peixe)
    {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        vsql = "SELECT [RGP], [PEIXE], [PESO], [QUANTIDADE], [DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE RGP = @RGP and PEIXE = @PEIXE and DATA_REGISTRO = @DATA_REGISTRO";

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime dtParam = DateTime.Parse(param_date);

                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RGP", param_RGP));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEIXE", param_peixe));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", dtParam));

                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objReader.Read())
                {
                    valor.retorna_RGP = objReader.GetInt32(0);
                    valor.retorna_nome_peixe = objReader.GetString(1);
                    valor.retorna_peso = objReader.GetDouble(2);
                    valor.retorna_Quantidade = objReader.GetInt32(3);
                    valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetDateTime(4);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }


        }
        else
            return false;


    }
```

Comment: You should not re-use SQL connections. ADO.NET has built in [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx), you should declare your `SqlConnection` objects in the scope you need them inside `using` blocks. As long as you pass in the same connection string a 2nd `SqlConnection` can re-use the connection from a previously disposed object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap your param_peixe in single quotes, like this:

```
objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PEIXE", "'" + param_peixe + "'"));
```

It wouldn't be the first time I've seen SQL reject the use of a string as a VARCHAR.

Comment: Ok its worth. Thanks.